# gnuplot: How to plot with variable linewidth?

Tags: vector, gnuplot

I have some issues with a plot i would like to make.

Let say I have a data file with 5 columns like: x,y,x+dx,y+dy, a .

I would like to plot a vector field with a arrow thickness proportional to a, but I don't know how to do it. Suppose I scale a in a way that  it belongs to [0:100], should I have to define a linetype for each interval [0:5],[5:10] etc... ?
I have tried with column function, but it is not working.

> c1=12
>
> plot 'data' u 3:4:($5-$3):($6-$4) w vectors lw column(c1)

(Note: the a term is in the twelve column)

And i tried this command:

> plot 'data' u 3:4:($5-$3):($6-$4):12 w vectors nohead arrowstyle variable

Comment: Please add some data from your data file and any code that you might've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last approach with the variable arrow style should work fine. Consider the following example:

```
set samples 11
set xrange [0:100]
set for [i=1:101] style arrow i lw i/10.0 nohead
unset key
plot '+' using 1:1:(2):(10):($1+1) with vectors arrowstyle variable
```

Here I defined 100 arrow styles which differ only in their linewidth. The result with version 4.6.5 is

[image]

In your case it should be enough to use

```
set for [i=1:101] style arrow i lw i/10.0 nohead
plot 'data' u 3:4:($5-$3):($6-$4):12 w vectors nohead arrowstyle variable
```

Of course you must make sure, that column 12 is in the range `[1:101]`. You could also use `stats` to determine the limits of the values in column 12 and write a function `map(x)` which maps the values of this column to the required range `[1:101]`.